# bamboo barbells/ unstable loads and research papers

Tags: strength, exercise-equipment, starting-strength, functional-strength

I've been told that there are lots of research papers on this new kind of barbell, but I can't find any of them on google scholar or research gate. Do such papers exist? If so could you give me a list of them? [image]

Comment: Try a google search with: unstable load bench press

Comment: Asking the community to google it for you isn't quite the types of questions we look for. If there's a specific reason why you're looking for research papers, maybe that would be better suited to the question? You can edit the question if there's something more specific, otherwise, I've closed it as a duplicate for another great question on the bamboo bar.